# ASP.NET Routing - Ignore routes for files with specific extension, regardless of directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Say I want to remove any mapped routes for files with a certain file extension.

```
 RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{root}.hello");
```

Works for any file that has the extension `.hello` in the root directory, however as soon as i go into any subfolders the 'ignore' rule isn't applied.

Ive tried lots of different combinations, but can't seem to get one that doesn't throw a compiler exception, or not work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [Phil's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx) regarding this.  Basically, you would do something like this:

Example 1: Do not perform routing for any request for all .aspx files:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
```

Example 2: Do not perform routing for any request for favicon.ico

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, use IgnoreRoutes (MVC Extension method)

```
Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*foo*}", new { foo = @"someregextoignorewhatyouwant"});
```

If you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, use [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler.aspx) which implements IRouteHandler.

```
routes.Add(new Route("*someregextoignorewhatyouwant*", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```