# How to ignore all of a particular file extension in MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

How do I configure an IgnoreRoute to ignore all files with a certain extension, regardless of what directory they're in?

If I do this, everything works and my Flash movie gets played:

```
routes.Ignore("community/123/plan/456/video/moviename.flv");
```

So the "123" and "456" sections are variable and can be any integer number. Obviously though, I don't want to do one of these for each movie NOR do I have a need to replace 123 and 456 with variable placeholders. This is only an example of one type of directory, there are Flash movies stored throughout the application so **what I need is an IgnoreRoute value that will ignore files that have a .flv extension no matter where in the hierarchy they are**.

I've tried the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.flv");
routes.IgnoreRoute("(.*).flv(.*)"); // Yeah I know, I'm horrible at RegEx
```

The only thing I can get to work so far is specifically passing the full relative path to the FLV file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Routing - Ignore routes for files with specific extension, regardless of directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228328/asp-net-routing-ignore-routes-for-files-with-specific-extension-regardless-of)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this article by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx

> Long story short, we didn’t want routing to attempt to route requests
>   for static files such as images. Unfortunately, this caused us a
>   headache when we remembered that many features of ASP.NET make
>   requests for .axd files which do not exist on disk.
>
> To fix this, we included a new extension method on RouteCollection,
>   IgnoreRoute, that creates a Route mapped to the StopRoutingHandler
>   route handler (class that implements IRouteHandler). Effectively, any
>   request that matches an “ignore route” will be ignored by routing and
>   normal ASP.NET handling will occur based on existing http handler
>   mappings.
>
> Hence in our default template, you’ll notice we have the following
>   route defined.
>
> ```
> routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
> ```
>
> This handles the standard .axd requests.
>
> ........
>
> We only allow one catch-all route and it must happen at the end of the
>   URL. However, you can take the following approach. In this example, I
>   added the following two routes.
>
> ```
> routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
> routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});
> ```
>
> What I’m doing here is a
>   technique Eilon showed me which is to map all URLs to these routes,
>   but then restrict which routes to ignore via the constraints
>   dictionary. So in this case, these routes will match (and thus ignore)
>   all requests for favicon.ico (no matter which directory) as well as
>   requests for a .aspx file. Since we told routing to ignore these
>   requests, normal ASP.NET processing of these requests will occur.

Comment: routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allflv}", new { allflv = @".*\.flv(/.*)?" });  <--- That did the trick, thanks.

Comment: @Coelho Can you explain your situation or post a new question if a comment is not enough to explain?

Comment: Sorry, here have my sitiation, basic is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637334/mvc-ignore-route