# MVC Ignore Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

how I create a Ignore route to a Virtual Directory inside my ASP.Net MVC website?

my website is IT02:8069 and I create a virtual directory IT02:8069/AVR01 because inside of this directory I have files with this  path IT02:8069/AVR01/2012/05/14/09/10/59000c00412.spx, but if I try connect in this path I get the erro 500.19. All files inside this path has are *.spx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated: try this: `routes.IgnoreRoute("AVR01/{*pathInfo}");`