# How to access the handler even if the file does not exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ihttphandler

Im using -  asp.net mvc.

```
targetFramework="4.6.1"
```

I created a handler that need to check if the image exist in the local folder , if exist - return the image , if not - it go to the server url image path and download from there to the local folder. and than return the image.

MyHandler : HttpImageHandler.cs

```
using SearchContentPortal.Core;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace SearchContentPortal.Handlers
{
    public class HttpImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
            var localfilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Images\media", fileName);
            //check if file not exists in local folder,  or the last modify file wasn't today
            if (!File.Exists(localfilePath) || (File.Exists(localfilePath) && (File.GetLastWriteTime(localfilePath).ToShortDateString() != DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))))
            { //if true - download the file to local folder
                DownloadAndSaveImage(localfilePath, fileName);
            }

            //return file stream
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/media/" + fileName));

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            }

            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
        }

        public static void DownloadAndSaveImage(string localfilePath, string fileName)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(AppSettings.ImagesBaseUrl + "/" + fileName, localfilePath);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My Web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="HttpImageHandler1" path="*.png" verb="*" 
      type="SearchContentPortal.Handlers.HttpImageHandler" 
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="HttpImageHandler2" path="*.jpg" verb="*" 
      type="SearchContentPortal.Handlers.HttpImageHandler" 
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

My image -

```
 <img src="~/Images/media/beauty_beast.jpg" alt="beauty and the beast"  />
```

**But it not works`** - not entered the handler.

And **if i have the image physically** in the "media" folder already. (if exist) - **it entered to the hadler**.

And i can't use in src - "Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?fileName=beauty_beast.jpg".
I mean without using ashx file ( HttpImageHandler.ashx ) like :

```
 <img src="Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?fileName=beauty_beast.jpg" alt="beauty and the beast"/>
```

i want to see in the src the path
like this:

```
 <img src="~/Images/media/beauty_beast.jpg" alt="beauty and the beast"/>
```

What is the right solution?

thanks!!

Comment: I would use a controller for that (ImagesController)

Comment: @Moran you would want that code to either be executed when the view is created, ie "index" portion of the controller.  Or you would want to actually have an Ajax event that occurs when the Dom is ready to call the handler, to retrieve the file.  Your using MVC by the way, you really don't need a handler file, a controller with actions can handle.

Comment: @Greg when the view is created.

Comment: did u debug? does it reach to HttpImageHandler.ProcessRequest?

Comment: @Moran You said you're using MVC, which you would create a Controller such as HomeController, with an action called Index.   When I navigate to site.com/Home the Index action would be a get, which would return a View. The check could occur then, you could even have an action that you hit with Razor so it does the check for you and returns the data.  @FileCheck(path) if it isn't there, do you stuff and return right path.

Comment: @DanielB yes, and it not reach to HttpImageHandler.ProcessRequest :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.Net Web Forms, it will work fine but in MVC, you need to ignore this path to be not  treated as controller-action path so:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/{*pathInfo}");
```

or generally

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/");
```

[ASP.NET Routing - Ignore routes for files with specific extension, regardless of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228328/asp-net-routing-ignore-routes-for-files-with-specific-extension-regardless-of)

Comment: @Moran glad could help